# ssh X forwarding not working on computers outside LAN when ControlMaster is set to auto

Tags: ssh, xforwarding

I can connect to machines on my local LAN using `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y` and X forwarding works. However, when trying to connect to machines outside my LAN, X forwarding fails.

I have narrowed down the problem to these lines in my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
##  Enable auto completion even when needing a password
## as long as one connnection to the server has been established.
Host *
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
  ControlMaster auto
```

This is the output of `ssh -vY` when my `~/.ssh/config` file contains *only* the lines above:

```
$ ssh -vYp 1234 terdon@123.456.78.9
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Debian-6, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/terdon/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/terdon/.ssh/config line 3: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 14
Last login: Tue Oct 15 20:12:24 2013 from foo.bar.net
terdon@server $ echo $DISPLAY

terdon@server $
```

Note that there is no line about requesting X11 forwarding, compare to the output below, apparently these option override the `-Y` or `-X` flag.
If the `~/.ssh/config` file is empty, the output of the command above includes (I am not showing the entire thing because it is very long and I think irrelevant, let me know if it is needed):

```
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
```

And X forwarding is successful:

```
terdon@server $ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:11.0
```

I tried

```
Host *
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
  ControlMaster auto
  X11Forwarding yes
```

and

```
X11Forwarding yes
Host *
  ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
  ControlMaster auto
```

But both give me this error:

```
Bad configuration option: X11Forwarding
```

#### System information:

```
$ lsb_release -icd
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    LMDE Cinnamon Edition
Codename:       debian
$ uname -a
Linux oregano 3.10-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.10.5-1 (2013-08-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.2p2 Debian-6, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
```

How can I allow X forwarding and keep the configuration options I have?

Comment: What if you use the correct name for the option? `ForwardX11` = `-X` or `ForwardX11Trusted` = `-Y`

Comment: Yup, that works.